# Unable to find active deployment pane on azure portal for rollback

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I used Visual Studio Team Services for deployment of an MVC website on azure and it was successful.

I also created deployment slots.

Now I would like to rollback the deployment, but I am unable to find the Active Deployment blade on portal.azure.com.

[image]

Update 1:

I went to Deployment Source>Choose Source>Visual Studio Team Service> Choose a project. When I clicked it, it did not show any project, although I have project on my Visual Studio Team Services.

I did it other way. I went to Visual Studio Team Services, and there established trust relationship between Azure and Team Services. I succeeded with deployment.
[image]

Comment: If you go to the Settings blade and find the Deployment Source menu item, does it say it is configured?  If it isn't, you'll need to configure it - then you'll be able to see the Deployments listing and redeploy what you want.

Comment: @JasonHaley I went to Deployment Source>Choose Source>Visual Studio Team Service> Choose a project. When I clicked it, it did not show any project, although I have project on my TFS online.
I did it other way. I went to TFS, and there established trust relationship between Azure and TFS online. I succeeded with deployment.

Comment: Yeah I had the same thing, my deployments work fine since I connected the VSO build to the Azure webapp, but the Azure portal didn't show the list of deployments until I went through the portal's Deployment Source menu to configure it.  All the choices where there, I just needed to connect it.  If you don't see the project, it could be a VSO security setting.  Are you the Azure account admin and the VSO project owner?

Comment: @JasonHaley I am unable to find where to set myself as owner. I tried this link:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-account-ownership-vs

Comment: I just noticed you also have a deployment slot, are you trying to access the deployment source from the slot you deployed to?  Example: for me I was able to connect it on my staging slot's settings -> Deployment Source.  Did you create the VSO project?  if so, then you should be ok.  If not, you probably can't make yourself owner.

Comment: @JasonHaley Yes Jason, I have created the project. But I am unable to see where I can verify this. I tried connecting via both deployment and production slot. Its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116928/discussion-between-jason-haley-and-aditya-bokade).

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be checked:

1. **Check whether you have linked a VSTS:**

[image]

2. **Check whether your team projects are using Git version control. When you select "Visual Studio Team Services" as deployment source from New Azure Portal, it is using [Kudu service](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) which is designed for Git version control. So it will only show the projects with "Git" repositories.**

[image]

> If you want to deploy the TFVC project, try with Azure Classic Portal.
>   You can refer to this article for details: [Continuous delivery to
>   Azure using Visual Studio Team Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/)